# jquery anchor click doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, click, anchor

Here is function ,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getRecordspage(1, 5);
        $("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
            alert(1);
            getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And in my page i am appending anchors dynamically to this div,

```
<div id="pager" class="pager">
//my anchors will be present here...
</div>
```

i am appending anchors dynamically... All anchors will have `class="page-numbers"`... How it can be done...

When inspected through `firebug` my pager div had this when i clicked `3`,

```
<div class="pager" id="pager">
<a class="page-numbers prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
<span class="page-numbers current">3</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="#">4</a>
<a class="page-numbers next" href="#">Next</a></div>
```

**EDIT:**

I using jquery 1.4...

```
function getRecordspage(curPage, pagSize) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        data: "{'currentPage':" + curPage + ",'pagesize':" + pagSize + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            var strarr = jsonObj.d.split('##');
            var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(strarr[0]);
            var divs = '';
            $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
            });
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
            $(".pager").pagination(strarr[1], { 
                current_page: curPage - 1, items_per_page: '5', num_display_entries
: '5', next_text: 'Next', prev_text: 'Prev', num_edge_entries: '1'
            });
            $(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
            $(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("resultshover");
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("resultshover");
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean with *click doesn't seem to work*? The alert is not executed?

Comment: @Felix ya thats right... See my `getRecordspage` function i am generating pagination.....

Comment: where are you creating the links?

Comment: @j look at the line `$(".pager").pagination(` my pagination plugin does it for me...

Comment: don't you get any errors on firebug?

Comment: @j no i didnt get any errors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("a.page-numbers").live('click',function() {
        alert(1);
        getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
        return false;
});
```

or execute your handler assignment **after** you created the links. If there are no elements with class `page-numbers` when this function is executed then of course nothing happens.

But `live()` takes care of that:

> *Description*: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

**Update:**

Well I am not sure. One thing you can try is to move your function inside the success function of the Ajax call:

```
function getRecordspage(curPage, pagSize) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        data: "{'currentPage':" + curPage + ",'pagesize':" + pagSize + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            // .. lot of stuff here..
            // at  the end:
            $("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
                alert(1);
                getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
                return false;
            }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: Then you have to provide more code. When/how do you create those links?

Comment: @Felix that too didnt work because i think pagination has a `callback` but when i used that too didnt work...

Answer (score 2):

you must use .live when you'll dynamically add elements.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      getRecordspage(1, 5);
        $("a.page-numbers").live('click', function() {
            alert(1);
            getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
            return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use jquery 1.42 and `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`:

```
$("a.page-numbers").delegate('click', 'a.page-numbers', function(){
    alert('1');
});
```

Comment: isn't it `$("a.page-numbers").delegate('a.page-numbers', 'click', function(){ ...` ?

Comment: @Matt: Seems to be new in 1.4.2 not in 1.4